# Mousekeys - moving by small or large increments

Tags: mouse, lubuntu

I'm using Mousekeys under Lubuntu. I'm wondering, is there a way to get the mouse to jump? Currently, when I hit 6, the mouse goes a tiny bit to the right. Is there a way (by pressing shift+6, for example) to get the mouse to jump 20 pixels to the right instead?

The cursor goes fast enough, I'm happy there, it'd just be nice to have the option when needed to hit shift and have the cursor leap and it occurred to me that it might already be a feature I just haven't been able to find.

Thanks,
-Sage